# how to extract links from a website and extract its content in web scraping using python

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a website using **beautifulSoup**  and **requests** packages
where I want to extract the links  and it contents .

Until now I am bale to extract the list of the links that exist on a defined **url** but I do not know how to enter each link and extract the text.

the image below describe my problem :
[image]

The text and the image are the link for the hall article.

## code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.annahar.com/english/section/186-mena"
html_text = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.content, features = "lxml")

print(soup.prettify())

#scrappring html tags such as Title,  Links, Publication date
for index,new in enumerate(news):
    published_date = new.find('span',class_="article__time-stamp").text
    title = new.find('h3',class_="article__title").text
    link = new.find('a',class_="article__link").attrs['href']
    print(f" publish_date: {published_date}")
    print(f" title: {title}")
    print(f" link: {link}")
```

result :

```
publish_date: 
                                                        06-10-2020 | 20:53
                                                    
 title: 

                                                        18 killed in bombing in Turkish-controlled Syrian town
                                                    

 link: https://www.annahar.com/english/section/186-mena/06102020061027020
```

My question is how to continue from here in order to enter each link and extract its content?

the expected result :

```
publish_date: 
                                                        06-10-2020 | 20:53
                                                    
 title: 

                                                        18 killed in bombing in Turkish-controlled Syrian town
                                                    

 link: https://www.annahar.com/english/section/186-mena/06102020061027020

description:

ANKARA: An explosives-laden truck ignited Tuesday on a busy street in a northern #Syrian town controlled by #Turkey-backed opposition fighters, killing at least 18 people and wounding dozens, Syrian opposition activists reported.

The blast in the town of al-Bab took place near a bus station where people often gather to travel from one region to another, according to the opposition’s Civil Defense, also known as White Helmets.
```

where the **description** exist inside the **link**

Comment: Share HTML code instead of the picture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional request to your loop that gets to the article page and there grab the description

```
page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features = "lxml")

description = soup.select_one('div.articleMainText').get_text()
print(f" description: {description}")
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.annahar.com/english/section/186-mena"
html_text = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.content, features = "lxml")

# print(soup.prettify())

#scrappring html tags such as Title,  Links, Publication date
for index,new in enumerate(soup.select('div#listingDiv44083 div.article')):
    published_date = new.find('span',class_="article__time-stamp").get_text(strip=True)
    title = new.find('h3',class_="article__title").get_text(strip=True)
    link = new.find('a',class_="article__link").attrs['href']
       
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features = "lxml")
    
    description = soup.select_one('div.articleMainText').get_text()
    print(f" publish_date: {published_date}")
    print(f" title: {title}")
    print(f" link: {link}")
    print(f" description: {description}", '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab all follow links to the articles and then loop over that and grab the parts you're interested in.

Here's how:

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get("https://www.annahar.com/english/section/186-mena").content,
    "lxml"
)

follow_links = [
    a["href"] for a in
    soup.find_all("a", class_="article__link")
    if "#" not in a["href"]
]

for link in follow_links:
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "lxml")
    date_published = s.find("span", class_="date").getText(strip=True)
    title = s.find("h1", class_="article-main__title").getText(strip=True)
    article_body = s.find("div", {"id": "bodyToAddTags"}).getText()

    print(f"{date_published} {title}\n\n{article_body}\n", "-" * 80)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output (shortened for brevity):

```
08-10-2020 | 12:35 Iran frees rights activist after more than 8 years in prison

TEHRAN: Iran has released a prominent human rights activist who campaigned against the death penalty, Iranian media reported Thursday.The semiofficial ISNA news agency quoted judiciary official Sadegh Niaraki as saying that Narges Mohammadi was freed late Wednesday after serving 8 1/2 years in prison. She was sentenced to 10 years in 2016 while already incarcerated.Niaraki said Mohammadi was released based on a law that allows a prison sentence to be commutated if the related court agrees.In July, rights group Amnesty International demanded Mohammadi’s immediate release because of serious pre-existing health conditions and showing suspected COVID-19 symptoms. The Thursday report did not refer to her possible illness.Mohammadi was sentenced in Tehran’s Revolutionary Court on charges including planning crimes to harm the security of Iran, spreading propaganda against the government and forming and managing an illegal group.She was in a prison in the northwestern city of Zanjan, some 280 kilometers (174 miles) northwest of the capital Tehran.Mohammadi was close to Iranian Nobel Peace Prize laureate Shirin Ebadi, who founded the banned Defenders of Human Rights Center. Ebadi left Iran after the disputed re-election of then-President Mahmoud Ahmadinejad in 2009, which touched off unprecedented protests and harsh crackdowns by authorities.In 2018, Mohammadi, an engineer and physicist, was awarded the 2018 Andrei Sakharov Prize, which recognizes outstanding leadership or achievements of scientists in upholding human rights.
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```